# What is the average amount of dice rolled when you add another die when a 5 or 6 appears?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

- Initially we roll 3 fair dice at the same time.
- Every time we roll a 5 or 6 on any of the dice we roll we will roll another dice.
- On average how many dice will be rolled in total? (including the initial
  3)

How would you go about calculating this? If you can point me in a direction where I can find out how to solve this myself that will be more than welcomed.
I'm stuck on the fact that I don't know how many dices will be rolled considering the fact that there's a chance that more will be added apart from the initial 3. I have no idea how I should even continue or where to start. I have little knowledge on statistics in general but if you can point me to the right direction where I can start learning or at least start a rabbit hole of learning I can take it from there. I made a program that conducted the question 15,000 times and it comes up to 4.5 rounded up. I would like to know how to solve it on paper rather than just brute forcing it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: It was good to ask for a pointer.  Your question asks for the expected value of a discrete random variable.  Those are the terms you should be searching for.

Comment: Try to write a recursive equation.  You always roll a die once, and a third of the time, you roll it again.

Comment: If my first three dice come up 4, 5, 6, do I roll one more die?  Or two?

Comment: If you roll two 5s in the original three, do you roll two more dice?  If so, you can consider each die independent.

Comment: if you get initially two or three 5 or 6 are you going to throw one die, or two/three ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat each die separately; the result is just three times the result for one die. For one die, let $x$ be the expected number of rolls. This is $1$ with probability $\frac46$ and $1+x$ with probability $\frac56$. Thus

$$
x=\frac46\cdot1+\frac26(1+x)\;.
$$

The solution is $x=\frac32$, so for three dice the expected number of rolls is $\frac92=4\frac12$. Since Ross' approach yields the same answer, it looks like there's a bug in your code that suggested the result was $4$.

Comment: Yeah there was a bug I fixed it and was getting approximately 4.5 when the experiment was performed 1 mil times. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  When you roll one die you have $\frac 13$ chance to roll another.  Each roll multiplies by another $\frac 13$, which makes it a geometric series to sum.  The three dice are independent, so you can multiply the result for one die by $3$

Comment: What I'm looking for is the average amount of dies rolled. I'd like a more concrete hint as in look up x and y and you can find out how to do it from there. The answer is 4 unless I'm a screw up as I made a program to conduct the experiment 15,000 times and it always comes up with a average amount of 4.

Comment: Thank you along with joriki's answer & yours I think I have a solid graph of it. Thank you for your answer!